# lxml.objectify can not parse attrib without quotes - need recover=Ttrue

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

Does anyone have any tips on how to use `lxml.objectify` with `recover=True`?

I have xml where the attributes are not quoted --> name=value instead of name='value'.

Below is some sample code... I do not have control over the XML formatting so I can not go back and have it changed. The `etree` parsing does work

The error is

```
File "<string>", line unknown
XMLSyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected, line 4, column 21
```

`lxml.objectify` CODE -- FAILS

```
xmlSample="""<dict>
<maptable>
  <hdterm displevel=1 autlookup entrytype=1>Source term</hdterm>
</maptable>
</dict>"""
```

If I don't get an answer do I have to re

```
import io
#p = objectify.XMLParser(recover=True)

root = objectify.fromstring(xmlSample)

# returns attributes in element node as dict
attrib = root.getattrib()

# how to extract element data
tbl = root.mytable

print("root.mytable type=%s" % type(tbl))
```

`lxml.etree` - WORKS!

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

import io
xmlIO = io.StringIO(xmlSample)

p = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

tree = etree.parse(xmlIO, parser=p)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag)
```

OUTPUT:

```
myxml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE :**

Turned out you can pass the `recover=True` option to `objectify.makeparser()` to create a parser that will try to recover malformed XML document. Then you can pass the created parser to `objectify.fromstring()`, like so :

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

xmlSample="""<dict>
<maptable>
  <hdterm displevel=1 autlookup entrytype=1>Source term</hdterm>
</maptable>
</dict>"""

parser = objectify.makeparser(recover=True)
root = objectify.fromstring(xmlSample, parser)

print(type(root.maptable.hdterm))
# output :
# <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
```

---

**INITIAL ANSWER :**

You can combine the two; `etree` with `recover=True` to fix the broken XML input, and then `objectify` to parse the well-formed intermediate XML :

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

xmlSample="""your_xml_here"""

p = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
well_formed_xml = etree.fromstring(xmlSample, p)
root = objectify.fromstring(etree.tostring(well_formed_xml))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Thought about this.  Actual XML are very large files and this approach will required parsing it 3 times: xml->etree, etree->good_xml, good_xml->objects.   Plus tracing data back to original XML could be problematic.

Comment: I guess there is no objectify.XMLParser(recover=True)?  Or way to replace objectify parser?

Comment: @frankr6591 I think I found the way to pass `recover=True` option to `objecdtify`! See **UPDATE** section above

Comment: I accepted your answer above as it is the best answer.   Yet, it did not resolve the root issue.   I finally had to use etree.iterparse because the combination of recover=True *and* html=True was needed to be forgiving for the xml I was parsing.